# ¿Cómo hacer la conexión ODBC en RStudio si el DNS es del sistema y no del usuario?

Tags: r, sql, dns, odbc

por favor su amable ayuda.

Estoy tratando de conectarme a las bases de datos en un sistema local y otro en la nube, desde el software R Studio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La conexión con la base grabada en DNS del usuario funciona (BASES) pero la que es grabada en el DNS del sistema no (ZIP), esta base es la que se encuentra en la nube.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema radica en que al ejecutar el comando sqlquery, para extraer la información, la tabla de la base BASES (gestion) se carga como un dataframe y ZIP me lee como un objeto (acc).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es:

```
library(RODBC)

ZIP <- odbcConnect("ZIP", uid = "", pwd = "")

BASES <- odbcConnect("Bangara_Bases", uid = "", pwd = "")

acc <- sqlQuery(ZIP, "SELECT * FROM cuentas") 

gestion <- sqlQuery(Bangara_Bases, "SELECT * FROM gestiones")
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: En `acc` tienes el mensaje de error, agregalo a tu pregunta para completarla. Pero en principio parece un error de conexión, ¿Cuando has creado el ODBC de sistemas, has hecho el test de conexión para ver si funcionaba?

Comment: Gracias tu ayuda. Y en efecto si funciona, la diferencia está en el tipo de conexión, la que no me funciona esta grabada en DSN del sistema, no del usuario.